# Right-click menu not opening

Tags: shortcut

I worked with Autodesk for 5 years and am now switching to Blender.

I changed a whole bunch of shortcuts for my keyboard and now, after I changed everything, I cannot open the right-click menu (the context menu) anymore when right clicking (even though I didn’t even change the right click shortcuts).

Usually it opened different menus depending on whether I’m in Object Mode or Edit Mode, but currently I can’t open any of the menus anymore.

How can I rebind those menus again so they show up?
Setting my keybindings to factory setting is not an option because I really need the Maya muscle memory shortcuts.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Edit > Keymap > Searching "Object Context Menu" (make sure "Name" is selected instead of "Key-Binding"). After that, you should be able to change that specific keybind.[image: Gif of how to do what I mentioned.]